# gulp error: "SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode"

Tags: npm, gulp

Running gulp on a recently checked-out JS project resulted in this syntax error.  A previous "npm install" had completed successfully, and it looks like all dependencies were met.  I am running gulp from the correct project folder and the gulpfile is resident.

Answer (score 1):

Solution = upgrade node.js to at least the LTS version.

Comment: I had the same issue and simply upgrading did not help. I also had to reinstall gulp after upgrading node.